# How can linear programming condition check if variable is a multiple of number?

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

Let's say we have linear programming problem

with x1 and x2 variables.

Maximize x1 + x2

where (for example)

0.3*x1 + 0.7*x2 <= 2

0.2*x1 + 0.3*x2 <= 3

How can be added one more condition, so linear programming solve should take into account,
that

x1 should come a multiple of 20 (or any other number) ?

something towards:

(1/20)*x1 + 0 <= something towards 20

So, for this example x1 variable,

right answer should be 20 or 40 or 60, ...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I mean, how to limit possible solved variable value, so it should be a multiple of any specific number:

for this example, X1 valid values are only 20, or 40, or 60,

otherwise, solve is not finished

Comment: @KamilIslamov Here is a possible constraint for x_1: $$\frac{x_1}{20} \in \mathbb N^+$$ So $x_1$ can take any value of $\{20,40,60,...\}$

Comment: @KamilIslamov Pay attention on the constraints. Both constraints do not allow that $x_1$ is greater or equal to $20$. With your mentioned condition the program is **not feasible**.

Comment: @callculus42. thanks for suggestion, 

would you please share,
 how can this condition be written down to A, b, c matrix of simplex method?

for this example:


       
A = [[0.3   0.7],[0.2   0.3]]


       
b =[2, 3]


c= [1, 1]


If to speak about ∈N+,
what should it look like for A, b, c?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to enforce the constraint that there exists an integer $k$ such that $x_1 = k \cdot 20$.
Once you enforce this type of constraint, you no longer have a linear programming problem.
In particular, the set of decision variables is no longer convex, because you're only allowing $x_1$ "on a grid" so to speak.

Once you add in constraints like this, your problem becomes one of "integer linear programming".

Comment: thanks for idea, for better interpreting, 

would you please share, how this condition could look like?

is it additional condition, or constant in target, or constant for right side?

Comment: This condition cannot be written as a system of linear equalities / inequalities. Instead, enforcing integrality is a new type of constraint. See this wikipedia article for more details [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming)

Comment: @KamilIslamov You would introduce $k$ as an integer variable and $x_1=20k$ as a new linear constraint.

Comment: @RobPratt , thanks for suggestion, 

would you please share, how this integer variable could be implemented with A, b c paradigm of simplex method of LP? 

where A = is coefficient matrix, "b" is right sides array, and "c" is target condition coefficients array? (A = [[0.3 0.7],[0.2 0.3]] b =[2, 3] c= [1, 1])

Comment: @KamilIslamov the main point here is that this is no longer an LP. You won't be able to write the feasible region using a system of linear inequalities. So, it generally doesn't make sense to use the simplex method as such, though there are many algorithms for integer linear programming, see the wikipedia link I sent above

Comment: thanks @ChrisHarshaw

when to speak about INTEGER LP method, I see examples with same structure of usage - A, b, c np.arrrays. 

So, how such multiply condition could be written for ILP problem conditions?

Comment: @KamilIslamov there's the additional constraint that the vector x must have integer entries. This is different from LP, where the vector x can have fractional entries. If you're interested in solvers for these programs, check out [this post on Stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502102/best-open-source-mixed-integer-optimization-solver)

Comment: @ChrisHarshaw , I have found more efficient way to be closer to MILP solve - devide some constraints to multiplier, and solve fractional or integer variables (instead requiring some variables as multipliers of specific number).  But now I'm looking for Native Python way to solve simplex-like problem with PARTIALLY integer variables. But I can't import c-based libs like mip. Are there similar solutions as https://github.com/ispaneli/lippy/ . but for partially integers? Those methods do not work, return zeroes or infinite loops

Comment: @KamilIslamov Glad you are using software and getting your hands dirty! :) I don't know what you mean by partially integer variables. Either way, given the software nature of what you're asking about now, perhaps it's best to ask a new question over at Stackexchange?